# Loop em função chamando ela mesma

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando criar um loop proposital para verificar se uma variável chegou ao valor pretendido, a ideia é criar uma função que dentro dela terá um `if`, que verifica se `cont == 4` no caso 4 é o numero de iterações anteriores a função, caso seja ele continua o processo caso ainda não seja `4` ele da um `setInterval` passando por parâmetro a `função` em `500 milissegundos`.

Abaixo o código:

```
      function verificaCont(){

        if(data.cont == 4){
          console.log(data);
        }else{
          setInterval(verificaCont(), 500); 
        }

      }
```

O erro que acontesce ao executar esta função é:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function.

Como posso resolver este problema ? ou existe algo para que eu possa ter para gerar um loop ?

> MOTIVO:
>   Preciso deste loop pois estou fazendo uma atividade que pretende salvar em um objeto vários dados, entre estes dados pode ser necessário a ida ao banco de dados, porém o banco utilizado é assíncrono, por este motivo preciso de um loop para que dê tempo de preencher todo o objeto.

Comment: Atualiza a pergunta com o código do for que você tem.

Comment: @Renan, JS foi feito para trabalhar de forma assíncrona, você poderia dizer qual é a linguagem server-side usada para acessar o banco? pois acredito que este loop seja desnecessário,  sendo que o que precisa é de uma função de callback.

Comment: @TobyMosque Eu utilizo o  IndexedDB, e quando vou ao banco busca ele continua passando para linha de baixo, e quando vou inserir ele não insere os dados. Mesmo que os dados esteja no objeto.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues, quando você faz uma requisição à uma objectStore, você tem dois eventos. "sucess" e "error", então você pode executar uma função de callback no "sucess" do request. Se estiver realizando múltiplas requisições, então crie um contador interno, e o quando o mesmo chegar ao numero de requisições feitas, você chama a função de callback.

Comment: então é interessante que você adicione a pergunta o seu trecho de código que acessa o IndexedDB, então posso te sugerir uma melhor forma para se trabalhar com ele.

Comment: @TobyMosque como ficaria ?  teria como me mostrar uma resposta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu disse, é para te dá uma resposta completa, seria interresante que posta-se o seu código com o IndexedDB, desta forma vou apenas postar uma resposta genérica.

por exemplo, vamos imaginar duas Tabelas, Usuarios e Pessoas, onde Usuarios possui um relacionamento de 1:N com Pessoas e queremos apenas o Logon de Usuario e Nome de Pessoa.

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["usuarios", "pessoas"]);
var usuarioStore = transaction.objectStore("usuarios");
var pessoaStore = transaction.objectStore("pessoas");

var UsuarioModel = function(usuarioID, callback) {
  var self = this;
  self.UsuarioID = usuarioID;

  var usuarioRequest = usuarioStore.get(self.UsuarioID);
  usuarioRequest.onsucess = function (event) {
    self.Logon = usuarioRequest.result.Logon;

    var pessoaRequest = pessoaStore.get(usuarioRequest.result.PessoaID);
    pessoaRequest.onsucess = function (event) {
      self.Nome = pessoaRequest.result.Nome;
      callback();
    }
  }    
}

var usuarioModel = new UsuarioModel(35, function () {
  console.log(usuarioModel);
});
```

No exemplo acima, a função de `callback` será executada o Nome for recuperado.

Agora vamos imaginar um segundo cenário, a entidade Usuarios e Pessoas são independentes, porem preciso esperar pelo retorno das duas requisições para executar algum código.

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["usuarios", "pessoas"]);
var usuarioStore = transaction.objectStore("usuarios");
var pessoaStore = transaction.objectStore("pessoas");

var UsuarioModel = function(usuarioID, pessoaID, callback) {
  var self = this;
  var sucessos = 0;
  var execCallBack = function () {
    sucessos++;
    if (sucessos == 2) {
      callback();
    }
  } 

  self.UsuarioID = usuarioID;
  self.PessoaID = pessoaID;

  var usuarioRequest = usuarioStore.get(self.UsuarioID);
  usuarioRequest.onsucess = function (event) {
    self.Logon = usuarioRequest.result.Logon;
    execCallBack();
  }    

  var pessoaRequest = pessoaStore.get(self.PessoaID);
  pessoaRequest.onsucess = function (event) {
    self.Nome = pessoaRequest.result.Nome;
    execCallBack();
  }
}

var usuarioModel = new UsuarioModel(35, 58, function () {
  console.log(usuarioModel);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

O [`setInteval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval) é uma função que executa uma determinada função **sempre** em um intervalo de tempo.

Se você quer fazer deste modo deveria usar o [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout) que executa apenas **uma vez** apos o intervalo.

#### Codigo

```
function verificaCont(){
    if(data.cont == 4){
        console.log(data);
    }else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            verificaCont();
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

#### Alternativa

```
function verificaCont(){
    this.checkCount = setInterval(function(){ 
        if(data.cont == 4){
            clearInterval(this.checkCount);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: o seu código está dando o seguinte erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues desculpe, achei que era possível fazer a chamada da função diretamente no primeiro parâmetro, mas aparentemente deve ser chamada dentro da função.