# Como fazer uma function aguardar por jQuery carregado com a tag async

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um problema para fazer uma function esperar o carregamento do pacote.js com a tag async

```
<script id="packjs" async type="text/javascript" src="pacote.js"></script>
```

Esse arquivo contém o jQuery e alguns plugins.O problema é que quando carrego com `async` eu tenho que arrumar uma forma de fazer as funções na página e aguardar pelo carregamento do pacote.js, achei algumas soluções que funcionaram no **FF** e **IE**, mais no **Chrome** as vezes não funciona dependendo da ordem de carregamento.

o que eu já tentei:

```
document.getElementById('packjs').addEventListener("load", chamoUmaFuncaoAqui,false);
```

Seria a solução perfeita, e funciona no **FF** e **IE**, mas no **Chrome**, não sei o porquê. As vezes esse evento não funciona e ativa a função logo no inicio, portanto antes do pacote.js. Tentei combinar com uma declaração de var no final do pacote.js e depois verificar se ela existe,

```
if (typeof pronto !== 'undefined') {
    chamoUmaFuncaoAqui();
}
```

mais também não funcionou.

```
function init() {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        // Código dependente do jQuery fica aqui
        tempo=Date.now()-timestamp;
        console.log('Alternativa Função init com setTimeout (se ocorrer depois de window.addEventListener load não funcionará):  '+tempo);
        //car_news();
        //Car_Com();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(init, 100);
    }
}
init();
```

O problema é que quando o carregamento é muito rápido, a diferença de tempo entre a função e o evento `window.addEventListener` load é de milésimos de segundos, e se for executado depois, não funciona.

[minha página com esse teste](http://www.investmax.com.br/iM/xteste02b22.html) e algumas das opções que ja testei. Deixei tudo com `console.log` pra acompanhar o problema.
Eu não tenho um conhecimento tão grande en javascript, mas creio que o problema tem ocorrido apenas no **Chrome** quando ele por algum motivo (creio que de forma errada) dá o `window.addEventListener` **DOMContentLoaded** antes de carregar o arquivo.js (isso não ocorre nos outros navegadores)

Algum sabe como contornar isso? Se puder ser com exemplo agradeço.

**Resolvido, (eu acho, rs).**
antes de chamar o arquivo.js adicionei:

```
var pronto = false; var feito=false;
```

de dentro do arquivo.js adicionei:
ronto=true;

```
if (feito==false && typeof executa !== 'undefined')
 {feito=true;executa('Chamado de dentro do Arquivo PACK.JS ');};
```

Na Pagina eu criei uma segunda chamada caso não tenha sido chamada ainda de dentro do arquivo.js

```
if (pronto==true && feito==false) 
{feito=true;executa('Chamado pela PAGINA ');}
```

Mas o que resolveu foi criar uma condição dentro da function executa para verificar se o document.addEventListener "DOMContentLoaded" já avia acontecido ou não. Isso porque no Chrome com async pode acontecer do arquivo ser carregado antes desse evento, isso me pareceu não ocorreu no FF e IE. Sendo assim, na página ficou assim:

```
function executa(a){
   if (DOMpronto==true) {
   /*o que precisar ANTES do DOM ter sido carregado*/
 }else{
   /*o que precisar DEPOIS do DOM ter sido carregado*/
 }
}

function evento(f) {
        if (window.addEventListener)
            {window.addEventListener("load", f,false);}
        else if (window.attachEvent)
            {window.attachEvent("onload", f,false);}
        else
            {window.onload = f;}    
}
var DOMpronto=false
evento(function(){console.log('carregoru DOM ');DOMpronto=true})    
if (pronto==true && feito==false) {feito=true;executa('pela PAGINA ');}
```

Dei uma resumida pro que é pertinente, mas basicamente é isso e funcionou.
Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Veja [setTimeout/setInterval](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90078/loop-em-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-chamando-ela-mesma/90086#90086), setTimeout só executa um vez, não seria necessário criam um loop?

Comment: No meu Chrome pareceu funcionar normalmente o seu callback. Mas tente isto: `document.getElementById('packjs').onreadystatechange = function() { if (script.readyState == 'loaded') { console.log("CARREGOU") } };`. Eu não ficaria monitorando com timers não, seria uma baita gambiarra.

Answer (score 1):

- Crie um `callback`
- Sete em seu arquivo a varivel como `true`
- Use `setInterval` para criar uma verificação continuar pela variavel

#### File1.js

```
var pronto = false;

function callback(){
    if(pronto == true){
        // ... codigo ...

        clearInterval(call);
    }
}

var call = setInterval(callback, 10);
```

#### File2.js

```
pronto = true;
```

#### Explicação

Em File1 você esta criando um loop que so termina quando `pronto == true`, pois ao final temos `clearInterval(call);`.

Comment: Obrigado por seu atenção, deu um problema parecido com o exmplo 2 q citei.
e as vezes ocorre depois do window.addEventListener load e não funciona
===================
Arquivo js carregado 73;
window.addEventListener DOMContentLoaded  82;
window.addEventListener load  154;
teste callback):  155;

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar a biblioteca [`gowiththeflow`](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/gowiththeflow.js) para lhe auxiliar com isto.

Para criar um fluxo de execução, instancia um objeto do tipo `Flow`, então chame o método `par` para executar algo em paralelo ou `seq` para ações sequenciadas.

quanto ao evento tag `script`, utilize o `load` e o `readystatechange` para fins de compatibilidade.

```js
var scripts = [
  { id: 'script1', flow: 'par', src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js' },
  { id: 'script2', flow: 'par', src: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js' },
  { id: 'script3', flow: 'seq', src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.0.0/globalize.js' },
  { id: 'script4', flow: 'par', src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.1/js/foundation.js' },
  { id: 'script5', flow: 'par', src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.js' },
  { id: 'script6', flow: 'seq', src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.10/js/dataTables.foundation.js' }
]

var loadScript = function (id, url, callback)
{
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  
  //compatibilidade entre Browsers;
  script.onreadystatechange = callback;
  script.onload = callback;
  
  script.id = id;
  script.async = true;
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = url;  
  
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}

var flow = new Flow();
[].forEach.call(scripts, function (script, indice) {
 
  flow[script.flow](function (next) {
    loadScript(script.id, script.src, function () {
      var date = new Date();
      console.log(script.id + " carregado às: " + date.toLocaleTimeString() + '.' + date.getMilliseconds());
      next();
    })
  });
});

flow.seq(function (next) {
  console.log('olha o jquery: ' + $)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/gowiththeflow.js/master/gowiththeflow.js"></script>
```

O script acima vai chamar os scripts `script1` e `script2` em paralelo... ao termino da execução dos mesmos, chama o `script3`, `script4` e `script5` em paralelo, ao termino destes chama o `script6`.

Segue o script minificado do `gowiththeflow` (606 Bytes) (você pode até colocar ele junto do script que carrega os demais scripts):

```
var Flow=function(){var d,a=[],b=setTimeout(function(){b=null;d._next()},0);return d={destroy:function(){b&&clearTimeout(b)},par:function(j,b){(b||!(a[a.length-1]instanceof Array))&&a.push([]);a[a.length-1].push(j);return d},seq:function(a){return d.par(a,!0)},_next:function(b,k){for(var e=[],f=[],g=a.shift()||[],h=g.length,i=1==h,c=0;c<g.length;c++)(function(a,c){a(function(a,b){e[c]=a;f[c]=b;0==--h&&d._next(i?e[0]:e,i?f[0]:f)},b,k)})(g[c],c)}}};
"undefined"!==typeof module&&"exports"in module&&(module.exports=Flow);"function"===typeof define&&define.amd&&define("Flow",[],function(){return Flow});
```

Comment: obrigado pela atenção, 
no caso eu só tenho um arquivo.js, e o que preciso é fazer a chamada na página html somente após a função estar disponivel, no caso o unico arquivo.js carrecago.

Comment: outro ponto nesse caso, é q alem de usar o async para deixar o carregamento mais rápido, não ter .js carregado de forma sincronica (sem async), ganha pontos no pagespeed do google, q influencia tb no ranqueamento nas busca do google. Logo carregar um outro arquivo auxiliar como jhead, ou labs, ou outro, pode resolver uma parte da sincronica, mas não pelo menos um arquivo vai acabar tendo q chamar sem async

Comment: o script minificado desta biblioteca tem apenas `606 bytes`, mesmo que você adicione ele no topo do seu script, o mesmo não deve aumentar o tamanho da sua aplicação de forma significativa, no final você pode ter apenas um pequeno script sendo carregado inicialmente, os demais scripts e estilos serão carregados dinamicamente por este primeiro.

Comment: no caso vc poderia me dar um exemplo de como chamar apenas um unico arquivo.js e chamar uma function na mesma pagina q estiver carregando essa biblioteca?
ou seja, como chamo a function dependendo desse arquivo carregado com o gowiththeflow?
 obrigado mais uma vez pelo retorno

Comment: Não aconselho que execute scripts dentro da pagina HTML, dê preferencia a arquivos externos, mas em todo caso, você pode fazer `flow.seq(function (next) { /*Seu script aqui*/; next() });`