# Qual a diferença entra setInterval/setTimeout e Web Workers?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estava dando uma olhada em alguns recursos do HTML5 e me deparei com esse WebWorkers cuja definição é:

> When executing scripts in an HTML page, the page becomes unresponsive
>   until the script is finished. A web worker is a JavaScript that runs
>   in the background, independently of other scripts, without affecting
>   the performance of the page. You can continue to do whatever you want:
>   clicking, selecting things, etc., while the web worker runs in the
>   background.

Bom, não consegui distinguir muito bem a diferença entre isso e o `setInterval` e `setTimeout`. Pelo que sei, esses dois disputam a thread do JS, possibilitando que o tempo programado para executar atrase ou algo do gênero, e caso tenha um intervalo de execução muito baixo, pode afetar muito a performance da página, certo?

Então olhei o [exemplo](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webworker) que o **W3S** tem em seu site e eis que me deparo com isso:

Index

```
<p>Count numbers: <output id="result"></output></p>
<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button> 
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support Web Workers.</p>

<script>
var w;

function startWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            w = new Worker("demo_workers.js");
        }
        w.onmessage = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...";
    }
}

function stopWorker() { 
    w.terminate();
    w = undefined;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

demo_workers.js

```
var i=0;

function timedCount() {
    i=i+1;
    postMessage(i);
    setTimeout("timedCount()", 500);
}

timedCount();
```

Dentro desse web workers, tem um `setTimeout`, que a cada *500ms* manda para a pagina a atualização do valor `I`. Então, por que não usar diretamente o `setTimeout`? Isso não faz sentido pra mim. Alguém pode dar uma luz, um conselho jedi?

Obrigado.

Comment: Relacionado : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90078/loop-em-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-chamando-ela-mesma/90086#90086

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### O setInterval

O `setInterval` é um loop assíncrono dentro do processo atual do javascript, ou seja ele roda na mesma camada que o processo maior apesar de não necessitar esperar, no entanto se ocorrer de haver muitas chamadas `setInterval` ou o callback dentro do `setInterval` for muito demorado ele irá de qualquer maneira travar o navegador (ou aba, existem navegadores como o Chrome e Firefox Developer Edition que usam multi-process).

O `setInterval` fica se repetindo infinitamente a cada intervalo definido, a não ser que você use `clearInterval` para para-lo.

### O `setTimeout`

Este é quase idêntico ao `setInterval` e também roda na mesma camada do processo atual do navegador ou aba, a diferença é que ele só é disparado uma vez e o `clearTimeout` não finaliza repetições apenas, ele pode finalizar um `timeout` no meio do caminho.

### O Web Worker

O Web Worker roda em uma camada isolada sendo mais semelhante a um `Thread` de verdade, tanto que **não é possível** controlar ou acessar elementos DOM diretamente pelo *Worker* pois são camadas diferentes, nele é necessário trabalhar com sinais (semelhante a ideia dos *Forms* em C++ por exemplo) é como se o arquivo `.js` chamado no Worker estive-se em um navegador separado, então com `postMessage` você envia respostas e com `worker.addEventListener('message', ...);` você captura, de ambos os lados.

Exemplificando:

- Para enviar uma mensagem de uma página chamada `foo.html` para o `baz.js` você terá que usar o `worker.postMessage` (`worker` é o nome de uma variavel de exemplo) e para ele pegar esta mensagem o `baz.js` terá que usar um `self.addEventListener('message', ...);` (o `self` é para se referir a ele mesmo).
- Para o `baz.js` enviar uma mensagem ao `foo.html` ele terá que usar `self.postMessage` e o `foo.html` terá que ter um evento assim `worker.addEventListener('message', ...);`.

Note também que o `Web Worker` não é suportado por alguns navegadores antigos.

### Resumindo

Com `setTimeout`/`setInterval` você pode interagir diretamente com a página atual mas ainda sim pode haver alguns problemas de travamento, mas na maioria dos casos eles são úteis, basicamente para intervalos mesmo.

Você deverá usar `Worker` quase for executar processos longos e geralmente síncronos que facilmente congelam uma página.

### Respondendo a duvida

O `setTimeout` dentro do `Worker` foi apenas para simular um longo processo, não quer dizer que ele seja algo real, é para entender como o Worker funciona, você poderia ter criado um loop dentro `while` gigante no Worker que teria o mesmo efeito, por exemplo edite o arquivo `demo_workers.js` para algo como:

```
var segundos = 20;
var initiate = Date.now() + (1000 * segundos);//Tempo que deve terminar o loop

postMessage(new Date().toString());

while (Date.now() < initiate) {
    postMessage(new Date().toString());
}
```

Note que longos loops travam o navegador, mas este seria um exemplo de como testar o Worker, o efeito será o mesmo para a camada da página html, pois estando dentro do WebWorker não irá afetar o navegador e não irá trava-lo, isto é apenas uma outra simulação de longos processos. Ou seja dentro do Worker você pode ter `setInterval` ou `while` longos, mas o que importa é que eles aqui são apenas exemplos e você deve usar o Worker quando houver a necessidade, tal como expliquei aqui:

- [Como liberar thread congelado/travado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100657/3635)
- [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635)
- [Por que as vezes é necessário o setTimeout com valor 0 (zero)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94853/3635)

Então o que quero dizer é que use *Web Workers* apenas quando necessário.

### Referencias:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers
- https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Entendi, então mesmo tendo um setInterval dentro do worker, ele não vai disputar com a thread principal e nem ter a chance de travar a ui, fazendo assim uma experiencia melhor para o usuário. Em termos de performance, ele consome muita memória e processamento?

Comment: @PauloGustavo  isso mesmo você entendeu bem. O consumo varia de navegador pra navegador e depende da sua aplicação.

Answer (score 5):

Neste exemplo realmente não faz diferença nenhuma. Tanto o thread principal quanto o thread do worker não estão fazendo praticamente nada.

Mas imagine que, em vez da função `timedCount` apenas incrementar um valor e postar uma mensagem (operações "leves"), ela tivesse realizando operações intensivas em CPU, algo que demore um tempo considerável. Nesse caso, se você tivesse essa função sendo executada no thread principal (i.e., o thread de UI), seria possível que o browser ficasse "travado" - já que o (único) thread não está disponível para receber interações do usuário.

Quando você coloca o processamento mais "pesado" em um web worker, o thread de UI continua disponível para atender às ações do usuário, e a página não fica   "travada" enquanto os cálculos estiverem sendo feitos. Quando o processamento estiver pronto para ser renderizado, o worker pode mandar uma mensagem pro thread principal já com o resultado do processamento.

Um exemplo concreto: a biblioteca [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) é usada para decodificar arquivos PDF e mostrá-los numa página web. Um arquivo PDF pode ser relativamente complicado, e fazer o parsing e a análise do seu conteúdo pode tomar um bom tempo. Essa biblioteca faz todo o parsing num worker, e quando precisa colocar algum elemento na UI (por exemplo, blocos de texto, imagem, fontes, etc.) o worker manda uma mensagem pra rotina principal da biblioteca.

Em relação ao comentário "qualquer processo que tenha a possibilidade de afetar a performance na ui é ideal usar o worker": não necessariamente. Em um ambiente de programação "tradicional", você tem uma operação a ser realizada, e vai executando as suas partes sequenciamente - isso potencialmente iria segurar o thread da UI por um bom tempo. Mas no mundo JS, a maioria das operações que podem levar um bom tempo (principalmente acessos a storage e a operações de rede) são **assíncronas** - você inicia a operação, ela *libera o thread*, e quando a resposta estiver disponível o seu código continua. Estes tipos de operação podem ser executados no thread principal sem problemas, já que o tempo de *processamento* é bem pequeno. Lembre que há um overhead em usar workers (mensagens, sincronização, etc.), e eles não são uma panaceia para resolver todos os problemas de performance da aplicação. Workers são úteis em aplicações que precisam bastante de tempo **de CPU, não operações que podem demorar.

Comment: Então, o web worker utilizada de uma thread unica e exclusiva dele? Nesse caso, qualquer processo que tenha a possibilidade de afetar a performance na ui é ideal usar o worker?

Comment: Atualizando a resposta, já que a explicação disso é meio longa...