# Atualização de Divs Randomicas

Tags: php, javascript

Nesse meu Script abaixo ele fica fazendo uma atualização de  uma divs puxando de um arquivo tv2.php de tanto e tento tempo... até ai ele funciona, mais o que eu preciso é que ele intercale entre dois arquivos.

Exemplo
           de 1 e 1 minuto troque conteúdo alternando arquivo tv1.php pra tv2.php em um loop

Como não tenho conhecimento de javascript que ria uma judinha de como posso corrigir esse código para isso

```
  <script>
  $(function () {
  function getContadorMapa() {
    $.get("tv2.php", function (result) {
        $('#latestData').html(result);
    });
  }

 getContadorMapa();
 setInterval(getContadorMapa, 20000);
 });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um simples uso de uma IF pode resolver

> Nota acho que o uso do `setInterval` assim pode conflitar, talvez seja melhor usar `setTimeout`, pra saber a diferença entre ambos **recomendo que veja** as seguintes respostas que fiz em outras perguntas:
>
> - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111149/3635
> - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635
> - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94853/3635

```
$(function () {
    var minutos = 1; //Um minuto

    var url1 = "tv1.php";
    var url2 = "tv2.php";

    var urlAtual = url1; //Coloque a url inicial

    function getContadorMapa() {
        $.get(urlAtual, function (result) {
            $('#latestData').html(result);
        }).always(function() {
            //Quando a requisição termina troca dispara always

            //Se a url atual for igua a url 1 então troca pra 2, caso contrário troca pra 1
            urlAtual = urlAtual === url1 ? url2 : url1;

            setTimeout(getContadorMapa, 60 * 1000 * minutos);
        });
    }

    getContadorMapa();
});
```

Se você precisar implementar mais urls no futuro use um array:

```
$(function () {
    var minutos = 1; //Um minuto

    var urls = [
                   "tv1.php",
                   "tv2.php",
                   "tvA.php",
                   "tvX.php",
                   "tvY.php"
               ];

    var i = 0; //Começa no item zero da array que no caso é o "tv1.php"
    var total = urls.length; //Pega o total de itens

    function getContadorMapa() {
        $.get(urls[i], function (result) {
            $('#latestData').html(result);
        }).always(function() {
            //Quando a requisição termina troca dispara always

            //Soma mais um a variável e assim passa para o proximo item do array
            i++;

            //Se i for maior que o tamanho do array então volta pra zero
            if (!(i < total)) {
                 i = 0;
            }

            setTimeout(getContadorMapa, 60 * 1000 * minutos);
        });
    }

    getContadorMapa();
});
```

Comment: Perfeito... Exatamente isso