# Como prevenir o cache em requisições Ajax no IE 6?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, cache

Tenho o código abaixo, para atualizar uma DIV em uma página:

```
var req;

// FUNÇÃO BUSCA ROMANEIOS PARA EXIBIR NA TELA DE MENU.
function buscarRomaneio() {

// Verificando Browser
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
   req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// Arquivo PHP juntamente com o valor digitado no campo (mÃ©todo GET)
var url = "PesquisaRomaneio.php";

// Chamada do método open para processar a requisição
req.open("Get", url, true);

// Quando o objeto recebe o retorno, chamamos a seguinte funÃ§Ã£o;
req.onreadystatechange = function() {

    // Exibe a mensagem "Buscando..." enquanto carrega
    if(req.readyState == 1) {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = 'Buscando Romaneios...';
    }

    // Verifica se o Ajax realizou todas as operações corretamente
    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {

    // Resposta retornada pelo PesquisaRomaneio.php
    var resposta = req.responseText;

    // Abaixo colocamos a(s) resposta(s) na div resultado
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resposta;
    }
}
req.send(null);
}
setInterval(buscarRomaneio, 60000); //Envia a informação a cada minuto
```

O que ocorre é o seguinte: Em qualquer navegador a função funciona normalmente. Menos no IE6, que será o caso exclusivo que irei usar (coletor de dados). A função funciona uma vez e para. Dou F5 inúmeras vezes e não muda nada. Só muda se eu limpo o cache ou fecho e abro o navegador.

Como se trata de um Windows CE 6, é tudo muito limitado. Tem algo que posso fazer nesse código para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Windows CE 6, IE6, cara, se tiver a chance, bota fogo nisso!

Comment: Qual é a versão do jQuery que você está usando?

Comment: Se você está trabalhando em uma empresa em que o diretor insiste em usar o IE6, então já passou da hora de você enviar o seu currículo por aí e fazer umas entrevistas.

Comment: O problema foram os coletores comprados... o valor foi alto e todos vieram nessa configuração. Estou mexendo no codigo e conforme altero ele os dados somem/aparecem.....

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento aberta.

Comment: Quem negativou, pode me dizer o que posso melhorar? A dúvida é valida, não entendi o porque do -1

Comment: @Diego eu não negativei, mas suponho que seja porque no titulo e tag fala jquery e no código não tem nada sobre jQuery. Vou editar e lhe dar +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, foi mal. A pressão aqui está grande e me perdi nos termos. Desculpe. E obrigado pela resposta, resolveu o problema :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Este problema de cache ocorria até mesmo nos *Internet Explorer* mais modernos (quando usando o ActiveX) e às vezes ocorre em outras situações, variando conforme o resultado do back-end.

As soluções práticas são:

1. Ajustar o cache via servidor no seu PHP:

   Edite o `PesquisaRomaneio.php` e adicione isso no topo, deve vir antes de tudo:

   ```php
   <?php
   $g = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s');
   header('Expires: ' . $g . ' GMT');
   header('Last-Modified: ' . $g . ' GMT');
   header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
   header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
   header('Pragma: no-cache');

   //Código restante abaixo
   ```
2. Adicionar uma *query string* de sufixo para evitar o cache. Esta é a mesma técnica que o jQuery utiliza para quando você adiciona `cache: false`. Faça assim:

   ```js
   // Arquivo PHP juntamente com o valor digitado no campo (método GET).
   var url = "PesquisaRomaneio.php";

   // Adiciona ? se não tiver query string. Caso contrário adiciona &.
   url += url.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&";

   // Adiciona o sufixo para evitar cache.
   url += "_=" + (new Date().getTime());

   // Chamada do método open para processar a requisição.
   req.open("GET", url, true);
   ```

## Dica

Recomendo trocar o `setInterval` pelo `setTimeout`. Isso porque o `setInterval` não espera, o que pode ocasionar em requisições simultâneas causando efeitos colateiras. Veja algumas respostas sobre o assunto:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111149/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/77765/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/77861/3635

Então, poderia mudar o código para algo como:

```js
function buscarRomaneio() {

    // Verificando Browser
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
       req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    // Ajusta os segundos
    var segundos = 60;

    // Arquivo PHP juntamente com o valor digitado no campo (método GET).
    var url = "PesquisaRomaneio.php";

    // Adiciona ? se não tiver query string. Caso contrário adiciona &.
    url += url.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&";

    // Adiciona o sufixo para evitar cache.
    url += "_=" + (new Date().getTime());

    // Chamada do método open para processar a requisição.
    req.open("GET", url, true);

    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = 'Buscando Romaneios...';

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {

        // Verifica se o Ajax realizou todas as operações corretamente
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                // Resposta retornada pelo PesquisaRomaneio.php
                var resposta = req.responseText;

                // Abaixo colocamos a(s) resposta(s) na div resultado.
                document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resposta;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "Erro: " + req.status;
            }

            setTimeout(buscarRomaneio, segundos * 1000);
        }
    };

    req.send(null);
}

// Inicia a função
buscarRomaneio();
```

Isso irá fazer o disparo sem precisar na primeira vez esperar os 60 segundos. Todavia, se quiser essa espera então troque por:

```js
    req.send(null);
}

// Inicia a função.
setTimeout(buscarRomaneio, 60000);
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, usei a segunda opção e funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Diego adicionei uma sugestão na resposta

Comment: Ótima dica, vou trocar. Obrigado!!