# Como fazer uma função rodar em tempo real

Tags: javascript, reprodutor-de-video, setinterval

Estou fazendo um *player* e gostaria de saber se tem uma função que fique executando o tempo inteiro, ou somente quando tal elemento é alterado.

No caso eu tenho essa função:

```
function updateTime() {
    var bufferedEnd = view.buffered.end(view.buffered.length- 1);

    videoLoader.style.width = String((bufferedEnd / view.duration) * 100) + '%';

    pctSeek = (view.currentTime / view.duration) * 100;

    progress.style.width = String(pctSeek)+'%';

    currentHour = Math.floor(view.currentTime / 3600);
    currentMin = Math.floor(view.currentTime / 60);
    currentSec = Math.floor(((view.currentTime / 60) % 1) * 60);

    timer.innerHTML = convertTime(currentHour, currentMin, currentSec);
}
```

Que faz a barrinha de carregamento do player atualizar o tempo todo e o tempo do video também.

Porém quando eu chamo essa função, eu chamo com um `setInterval`:

```
intervalTimer = setInterval(updateTime, 10);
```

E isso está deixando o site muito lento (pelos milésimos de segundo).

Eu tentei deixar um tempo maior, porém como a barrinha de *load* carrega junto com essa função, ela estava travando se você fosse arrastar (porque ela executava a cada 100 milissegundos).

Eu tentei usar o `resize()` só que também não funcionou.

Comment: Gabriel, você já deu uma olhada no VideoJS? É uma framework de Player de Vídeo HTML5, dá uma olhada em como eles fazem essas coisas e se baseie neles, eles tem uma ótima documentação :)

Comment: se você utilizar 10ms estará fazendo 100x por segundo (muito maior do que a maioria dos monitores que é apenas 60fps)... eu recomendo você impor limites como: atualizar somente se houver diferença de porcentagem (ex: de 34% para 35% você atualiza o width, mas de 34% para 34% não faça nada). E também não atualizar mais vezes que o monitor suporte; utilize isso (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 0):

Não vou responder ao titutlo, porque de fato não é bem o que precisa, vou lhe explicar sobre as diferenças básicas de setTimeout e setInterval.

Como expliquei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111149/3635

- `setInterval` executa deliberadamente sem esperar que a função termine para inicia-la novamente, ou seja com `10` milionésimos de segundo, ou seja muito menos que 1 segundo, a execução fica se repetindo, várias chamadas ao elemento DOM via `innerHTML` fica se "atropelando", o setInterval vai gerando e gerando cada vez mais, sem controle e sem limite
- `setTimeout` só executa uma vez, ou seja para chamar ele teria que executar novamente, o que resolveria o seu problema, executar ele após o `innerHTML`

A culpa não é do `setInterval`, ele tem um propósito especifico, mas não serve para o seu caso, para a maioria dos casos `setTimeout` resolve perfeitamente, isso já resolveria seus problemas:

```
var pausado = true;

function updateTime()
{
    //Se pausado for true então impede outra repetição
    if (pausado) return;

    var bufferedEnd = view.buffered.end(view.buffered.length- 1);

    videoLoader.style.width = String((bufferedEnd / view.duration) * 100) + '%';

    pctSeek = (view.currentTime / view.duration) * 100;

    progress.style.width = String(pctSeek)+'%';

    currentHour = Math.floor(view.currentTime / 3600);
    currentMin = Math.floor(view.currentTime / 60);
    currentSec = Math.floor(((view.currentTime / 60) % 1) * 60);

    timer.innerHTML = convertTime(currentHour, currentMin, currentSec);

    setTimeout(updateTime, 10);
}

function iniciar()
{
    //Só iniciará novamente já estiver pausado, caso contrário não faz nada
    if (pausado) {
        pausado = false;
        updateTime();
    }
}

function pausar()
{
    pausado = true;
}
```

Então você terá duas funções para uso, `iniciar()` para iniciar a execução e `pausar()` que irá parar a execução.

Comment: Eu havia conhecimento sobre o setTimeout, o problema é que ele chama a função **após** um intervalo de tempo, e não **durante**. No caso que você ajustou acima, ele executaria somente uma vez quando não estivesse pausado.

Mas a barra do progresso pode alterar tanto quanto pausado ou não, o "arrastar para chegar numa parte do filme". Eu só utilizei o setInterval por causa disso.

Comment: @GabrielArcuri setTimoeut chama uma vez se for chamado "fora" se estiver dentro da função toda vez que ela terminar ela é chamada novamente. Ou seja, terá quase o mesmo efeito do setInterval, mas não irá ficar fazendo chamadas "descontroladas"